# Convert to PDF with Attachments not Working With Outlook 2010

Tags: email, pdf, fonts, microsoft-outlook-2010, adobe-acrobat

I've got a user who is getting emails from a variety of different people. They normally Convert to Adobe PDF from the Outlook right-click menu, this would normally print the email using the standard font size and add the attachment at the end.

For some reason, the email itself is in exceptionally small text on some emails, to the point where it is not readable unless you zoom in by like 500%.

There is no visible difference between the fonts in emails that convert correctly and the ones that don't. I've tried printing using PDFCreator and using the Print Attachments option in the standard printer options window and all it ends up doing is printing the attachment itself, it doesn't print the affected email for whatever reason.